# How to set the System.Web.WebPages.WebPage.Model property

Tags: asp.net-routing, asp.net-webpages

I am planning on creating a custom route using ASP.NET Web Pages by dynamically creating `WebPage` instances as follows:

`IHttpHandler handler = System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpHandler.CreateFromVirtualPath("~/Default.cshtml");`

How can I supply an object to the underlying `WebPage` object so that it can become the web pages's "Model"? In other words I want to be able to write `@Model.Firstname` in the file `Default.cshtml`.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

By modifying the answer by @Pranav, I was able to retrieve the underlying `WebPage` object using reflection:

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        //var page = (WebPage) System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpHandler.CreateFromVirtualPath(this.virtualPath);

        var handler = System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpHandler.CreateFromVirtualPath(this.virtualPath);
        var field = handler.GetType().GetField("_webPage", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
        var page = field.GetValue(handler) as System.Web.WebPages.WebPage;

        var contextWrapper = new HttpContextWrapper(context);
        var pageContext = new WebPageContext(contextWrapper, page, context.Items[CURRENT_NODE]);

        page.ExecutePageHierarchy(pageContext, contextWrapper.Response.Output);
    }
```

Unfortunately this is not reliable as it does not work in Medium Trust (BindingFlags.NonPublic is ignored if application is not running in full trust). So while we have made significant progress, the solution is not yet complete.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Model property of a WebPage comes from the WebPageContext. To set a Model, you could create a WebPageContext with the right parameters:-

```
var page = (WebPage)WebPageHttpHandler.CreateFromVirtualPath("~/Default.cshtml");
var httpContext = new HttpContextWrapper(HttContext.Current);
var model = new { FirstName = "Foo", LastName = "Bar" };
var pageContext = new WebPageContext(httpContext, page, model);

page.ExecutePageHierarchy(pageContext, httpContext.Response.Output);
```

The model instance should now be available as a dynamic type to you in your page.

Comment: Hi @Pranav, I get an **InvalidCastException:** `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpHandler' to type 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPage'.` on the line: `var page = (WebPage)WebPageHttpHandler.CreateFromVirtualPath("~/Default.cshtml");`. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like `WebPage` is a private property of `WebPageHttpHandler`

Comment: Woops, serves me right for not checking my code before responding.
Use the CreateFromVirtualPath method hanging off of WebPageBase instead to make this work

var page = WebPage.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(@"~\Page.cshtml");